# How to enforce creating new transaction in Lift Mapper?

Tags: scala, transactions, lift, lift-mapper

We are using Lift + Mapper (version 2.4) in our project. We as well are using transaction-per-request pattern `S.addAround(DB.buildLoanWrapper())`.

In one of our requests we need to have nested transaction which we found to be problematic. We found that one of possible 'hacks' is to start transaction in a separate thread (like in example below) because `DB` object uses `ThreadLocal` to manage current connection and transaction state info.

Is there any implementation that is better (more safer and without multi-threading) than the one bellow?

```
  import net.liftweb.db.{DefaultConnectionIdentifier, DB}
  import akka.dispatch.Future

  /**
   * Will create a new transaction if none is in progress and commit it upon completion or rollback on exceptions.
   * If a transaction already exists, it has no effect, the block will execute in the context
   * of the existing transaction. The commit/rollback is handled in this case by the parent transaction block.
   */
  def inTransaction[T](f: ⇒ T): T = DB.use(DefaultConnectionIdentifier)(conn ⇒ f)

  /**
   * Causes a new transaction to begin and commit after the block’s execution,
   * or rollback if an exception occurs. Invoking a transaction always cause a new one to be created,
   * even if called in the context of an existing transaction.
   */
  def transaction[T](f: ⇒ T): T = Future(DB.use(DefaultConnectionIdentifier)(conn ⇒ f)).get
```

Comment: Using `Future(...).get` is completely pointless since it uses two threads instead of one; please remove that and the Akka tag, since this question is not related to Akka.

Comment: What do you mean by a "better" implementation?
If you use pure squeryl, you can decide this for yourself.
If you use just Mapper, AFAIK, you can choose the transaction scope for yourself, too.

Comment: to Roland Kuhn: Future is used here precisely to create a separate thread of execution 
Description should be improved as it lacks necessary explanation which is:
if you have DB.use around your request by using loan wrapper then it's one of (and I don't yet know another one) approach of how to force new transaction. Because of usage of Thread Locals simple nested DB.use does absolutely nothing

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be an existing API. You can ask about adding one on the google group. However there's nothing stopping you from doing something like:

```
DB.use(DefaultConnectionIdentidier){ sc =>
  val conn: java.sql.Connection = sc.connection
  // use regular JDBC mechanism here
}
```